# How to get app uses time in android

Tags: android

I am creating a custom launcher in android application and , I want to track actual time which application is opened.

suppose i open Facebook for 10 minute and I went ideal for 5 minute how to calculate 5 minute which is used by user.

Thanks

Comment: You can use package manager to retrieve application time usage, for pre-Lollypop devices, and UsageStats for API >= 21 (Lollypop devices). You need to keep a service running to track the time. Though not one of the best methods to do this, so maybe someone else can suggest something better.

Comment: @gauravjain can i have some example code ?

Answer (score 0):

You can define two buttons to start and stop your service. Fire an intent on Start button something like this:
            `Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent();
            startServiceIntent.setClass(this, MainService.class);
            startServiceIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName(this, MainService.class));
            bindService(startServiceIntent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);`

In the service, you can define broadcast receivers to detect screen on-off events.

```
private BroadcastReceiver screenWakeUp = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON")) {
            isRunningForegroundAppsThread = true;
            isScreenOn = true;
            startThread();
        }
    }
};
```

From here, you can start a thread which constantly runs inside a loop and checks whether the application being used by the user has changed meanwhile. If it has, you may update time for that app in the map else you can just continue. At the SCREEN_OFF event, you may stop the thread as user is no more using the phone.

You can retrieve the application name using this:

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            PackageManager pm = mContext.getPackageManager();
            ApplicationInfo af = null;
            List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
            // String activity = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getClassName();
            ComponentName c = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
            String packageName = c.getPackageName();
            try {
                af = pm.getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0);
            } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String app_Name_current = (String) pm.getApplicationLabel(af);
```

It solely depends on your requirement, and if needed the time can be stored in a DB. Also, this records just the time for apps which require screen to be ON, so you'll have to separately maintain time for background apps and store that in a separate map maybe. At the end, when you press the stop button, you can display the results in a listview or whatever UI element you consider suitable for this.

I know this is not complete code, but I guess it gives you an idea of how to go about it. Also, I'd say that though this might solve the problem, but it's not a good way of achieving the same, as PackageManager objects are heavyweight and dealing with them continuously is expensive operation.

The above approach only works on pre-L devices as ActivityManager has been deprecated in API level 21. So you have to use UsageStats class for Lollypop devices.